# RegEx for current year and anything between the current year plus 10

Tags: regex

Im trying to create a regEx that will validate the current year and any year after that up to 10. So if the current year is 2015 the use can enter any year between 2015 and 2025. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want a regex for this? Just grab what the current date is (via whatever language you're using), grab the year part, and see if whatever you're checking is at least as big as `current_year` (or whatever) and no more than `current_year + 10`.

Comment: Not possible (unless you use a different regex for each year). "current year plus ten" is not a pattern you can match. Something like "2015 to 2025" is.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's simpler to just use x <= currentYear + 10 and x >= currentYear. A regular expression is definitely the wrong tool.

Comment: Makes sense, Im using angularJS 1.3 for this.

Comment: This is a input text fields and Im using ng-messages for the errors

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not supposed to be used for numerical range checks, as @R. Martinho Fernandes suggested.

If you *really*, *really* need to use a regular expression, you *could* use something like so: `\b20(1[5-9]|2[0-5])\b`. You will need to change this every year.

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy solution for this:
in the angular controller:

```
 $scope.startTermDate = new Date();
 $scope.startTermYear = $scope.startTermDate.getFullYear();
```

on the form input I used ng-minLength="startTerm":

```
<div data-ng-if="programEditForm.academicYear.$touched"
    data-ng-messages="programEditForm.academicYear.$error">
   <span class="help-block" data-ng-message="minlength">Cannot be less than current year</span>
 </div>
```

Works pefect!!!